# Comparing code prior to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get an idea of what c# code looked like before LINQ came out.

I have tried searching for this for several weeks and came up empty. I understand how LINQ works but say you have a list of objects but you are trying to just locate a small amount. How would you have done this before LINQ?

Example of LINQ (excuse my syntax error, I'm still learning) :)

```
 list<employee> newlist = new List<employee> {john, smith, 30}
    newlist.add{jane, smith, 28}
    newlist.add{greg, lane, 24}

var last
from name in newlist
where name.last.equals("smith")
select name

foreach(var name in last)
{
Console.WriteLine(last);
}
```

How would you be able to sort through and locate the name of employees by last name and display them?

Comment: `for`/`foreach` + `if`..

Comment: You are not asking for sorting but for filtering

Comment: While most of the answers are giving code typical of the era, [yield return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) did proceed LINQ. Understanding `yield return` is essential to understanding many of LINQ's operators.

Comment: @TomBlodget - Why do you say that understanding `yield return` is essential to understand many LINQ operators?

Comment: @Enigmativity `yield return` is the foundation for the lazy-iteration of `IEnumerable` which is what LINQ is all about; generating a query that you can then lazy iterate over.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - There's nothing about `yield return` that makes it inherently lazy. It could easily be implemented in the compiler as a non-lazy sequence. I would say that `yield return` is not the foundation of lazy-iteration - it's just an implementation of it. `IEnumerable` was around long before `yield return`.

Comment: @Enigmativity While thats technically true; the MSDN definition of the keyword pretty strongly implies that its purpose is lazy-iteration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just the traditional way. Loop through and filter.

```
var smiths = new List<string>();
foreach (var employee in newlist)
{
   if(employee.Last == "smith")
   {
       smiths.Add(employee);
   }
}

return smiths;
```

For sorting, you can pass a delegate to the Sort() method. LINQ is just syntactic sugar on top of it.

```
newlist.Sort(delegate(Employee e1, Employee e2)
{
      //your comparison logic here that compares two employees
});
```

Another way to sort is to create a class that implements IComparer and pass that to the sort method

```
newlist.Sort(new LastNameComparer());

class LastNameComparer: IComparer<Employee>
{
   public int Compare(Employee e1, Employee e2)
   {
       // your comparison logic here that compares two employees
       return String.Compare(e1.Last, e2.Last);
   }
}
```

Looking at all this code, LINQ is such a time saver :)

Answer (score 2):

It's really the same number of lines of code, just more curley braces.

Here's a translation:

```
List<employee> newList = new List<employee> 
{
    new employee {First = john, Last = smith, Age = 30},
    new employee {First = jane, Last = smith, Age = 28},
    new employee {First = greg, Last = lane, Age = 24},
}

// Original code:                 // Pre-Linq translation:
var last                          // Becomes: var last = new List<employee>();
from name in newList              // Becomes: foreach (var name in newList) {
where name.Last.Equals("smith")   // Becomes: if (name.Last.Equals("smith") {
select name                       // Becomes: last.Add(name) } }

// Pre-Linq code:
var last = new List<employee>();
foreach (var name in newList) 
{
    if (name.Last.Equals("smith") 
    {
        last.Add(name) 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy. You are looping through all your items in a list and taking(mean copying references to other list) the ones you are looking for:

```
var smiths = new List<Persons>();
// get all Smiths and print them
foreach(var item in newlist)
{
    if(item.last == "smith")
        smiths.Add(item);
}

foreach(var item in smiths)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```